# How to resolve 12008 - Error performing bulk get operation In couchbase

Tags: powerbi, couchbase, sql++

When i try got get more then 5 lacks records im getting this error, i spent long time but the exception did not resolved., please help me the same.

[image]

And also i have tried from power bi same error throwing

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE covering index https://blog.couchbase.com/create-right-index-get-right-performance/

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON data_MY (owner, startDate, attributes.screen)
WHERE type_ = "Event";

SELECT owner, attributes.screen, DATE_FROMAT_STR(startDate, "1111-11-11") AS startDate
FROM data_MY
WHERE type_ = "Event" AND owner IS NOT MISSING;
```